# react-router history using CommonJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, commonjs

The React-Router documentation shows that for including browser history you include it like such:

```
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router'
. 
. 
.     
<Router history={browserHistory} />
```

How does one do this with CommonJS?

When I try it using the import method I get `Illegal import declaration while parsing file`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `import` syntax isn't implemented in browsers yet (hence the error you're getting, I'd imagine), so you need a transpiler like Babel to use it. The equivalent CommonJS syntax is:

```
var browserHistory = require("react-router").browserHistory
```

It mentions this on the [GitHub page](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/#installation) (although it doesn't specifically mention `browserHistory`).

Answer (score 1):

Humm, you can try like that:

```
var browserHistory = require('react-router').browserHistory
```